# Why I can not create a default method in an interface?

Tags: java, oop, interface, default-method

I'm just a newbie and learning about interfaces. I've tried to read some queries here before posting this. But it seems that it's too complex for me. And they're talking about default Object methods. In my case, I'm trying to create a default method in an interface but I get this error:

```
 "Syntax error on token "default", delete this token"
```

Here is my code:

```
package bankaccountapp;

public interface IBaseRate {

    // Write a method that returns the base rate
    default double getBaseRate(){
        return 2.5;
    }

}
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: If you are using Java 7 or earlier, this won't work.

Comment: You can have method definition only in Java version 1.8 or above.

Comment: Oh okay. I don't know that. The compiler compliance level is just until 1.7. I think I need to update. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to check jdk version

> default method in interface available from jdk1.8=>

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html